# SQL Server 2008 R2, Hebrew returned as question marks

Tags: sql-server, encoding, iis-7, asp-classic

I've got an ASP Classic site hosted on IIS 7, powered by SQL Server 2008 R2.

The data in the tables of the DB is in Hebrew. 
The problem is that when I try accessing the data from the site (as opposed to the SQL Enterprise Manager, for example), I get all the data as question marks. 
Same thing when I'm submitting data from the site: the tables get question marks.

Such problems had been discussed here before, I know. 
BUT:

- The collation of the DB is already Hebrew.
- The text columns are already nchars.
- Even when I make a simple test table with a single (nchar) column, and insert Hebrew text into it from the Enterprise Manager - using the correct Unicode syntax *N'TheText'* - the site still displays it as *'????????'*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `Response.Codepage=65001` and `Response.CharSet="UTF-8"` to the top of the asp page

Comment: Do what Alex suggests.  Also, open your asp page in notepad and select Save As from the File menu.  If the encoding is set to ANSI then change it to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I had the same problem, on my development machine it was set Hebrew as standard non unicode encoding, on the production server it was English(United States), after I changed it to Hebrew(Israel), everything worked fine.

By It I mean the Standard Non-Unicode encoding on the Machine